# SQL - update info in a specified column for multiple rows

Tags: sql, json, sql-update, jsonb

I have an SQL table laid out like so

| Column | Type | Modifiers |
| --- | --- | --- |
| uuid | uuid | not null |
| name | character varying |  |
| type | character varying |  |
| info | jsonb |  |
| created | bigint |  |

Inside the info column is numerous things such as `{"id": "1402417796043342360",  "colour": "blue", "subtype": "test", "description": "8.7"}`

However, I need to update `subtype` to `subType` inside the info column for numerous rows. Basically, anywhere that has `subtype` needs changed to `subType`

Is there an easy way to specify this change within the column?

I tried `UPDATE table_name SET info = REPLACE('info', '"subtype"', '"subType"');`

but got the error `ERROR:  column "info" is of type jsonb but expression is of type text LINE 1: UPDATE table_name SET info = REPLACE('info', '"su... ^ HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be using Postgres, as denoted by the use of datatype `jsonb`, which is specific to this database.

> Basically, anywhere that has `subtype` needs changed to `subType`.

Here is one way to do this in Postgres :

```
update t 
set info = info - 'subtype' || jsonb_build_object('subType', info -> 'subtype')
where info ? 'subtype'
```

The `where` clause filters on rows whose jsonb that contain key `'subtype'`. The `set` clause updates the object by removing the offending key (using operator `-`), then adding the relevant key/value pair (using `||`).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server you can try [SQL_MODIFY](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/sql/t-sql/functions/json-modify-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

The specific query for your case could be

```
UPDATE table_name
SET info = JSON_MODIFY(info, '$.subtype.*~', 'subType')
```

The only thing that needs to be tested is that .*~ return the dict key.

Another solution could be using the json column as a simple string and operating a replace (maybe you should have to do some casting)

```
UPDATE table_name
SET info = REPLACE(info, '"subtype"', '"subType"')
```

[REPLACE](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) is supported by multiple SQL Dialects

Comment: Hi, I tried JSON_MODIFY and got the error ```ERROR:  function json_modify(jsonb, unknown, unknown) does not exist. HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.``` and for REPLACE I got the error ```ERROR:  column "info" is of type jsonb but expression is of type text. HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.```

Comment: Yes, you should try casting the column with the replace method something like
`UPDATE table_name
SET info = CAST(REPLACE(CAST(info AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), '"subtype"', '"subType"') AS JSONB)` I'm not sure of the sintax as I'm not aware of your SQL Dialect

Comment: Maybe this could work in postgres:
`UPDATE table_name SET info = to_json(REPLACE(CAST(info AS text), '"subtype"', '"subType"'))` but I assume @GMB knows way better postgres and I would first try his response